# What is better way to making longer delay inside a series of tasks?

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduling

I'm trying to build a workflow system, which will process a series of tasks & delays. Delay can be changed or removed from a running workflow.

What is the better way to making longer delay inside a series of tasks? (Like 3-4 months). Right now two ways are pocking around my head:

1. Pre-calculating & saving delay time. Setup a scheduler that will check delay repeatedly after a specific interval(1 minute maybe). This will make a lot of database queries, but the delay can be changed instantly.
2. Schedule a job for a delay. This can reduce a lot of database queries &, but the problem is maintaining & changing delay in these long-running jobs. Also, these jobs need to survive a server crash or restart.

Right now I'm not sure how to do it in a better way and still studying about it. If anyone has a similar experience, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the tasks into the database, like :

```
{
   _id: String,
   status: Enum,
   executionTime: timestamp,
}
```

---

When you declare a new task, push a new entry into the DB.

---

At your server start, or when a new task is declared, create a `setTimeout` that will wake up your node.js when it's necessary.

---

**Optimization**

To avoid having X `setTimeout`, with X the number of task to execute. Keep only one `setTimeout`, with the time to wait equals to the closest task to execute.

For example, you have three task, one must run in 1 hour, one in 2 hour and one in 3 hour. Use a `setTimeout` of 1 hour. When it get triggered, it execute the task 1 and then look at the remaining tasks to re-run.